# Tips on how to calculate the age on PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I created an SQL script:

[image]

```
 {CREATE TABLE ator (
    id               NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    nome_artistico   VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
    nss              NUMBER(11),
    sexo             CHAR(1),
    nacionalidade    VARCHAR2(15),
    email            VARCHAR2(30),
    telefone_fixo    VARCHAR2(12),
    telefone_movel   VARCHAR2(12),
    dt_nascimento    DATE,
    CONSTRAINT ator_pk PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);}
```

My question is: Does anyone has a tip on how to calculate and print the age of x actor? I'm great at SQL but not so good on PL/SQL so if anyone could give a tip I would appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `months_between` as follows:

```
Select t.*, trunc(months_between(sysdate, dt_nascimento) / 12) as age
  From ator t
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're interested in PL/SQL solution, I'd suggest you to use a **function**: pass actor's `ID` to it and return actor's age. A simple example:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_age (par_id in ator.id%type)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    l_age number;
  5  begin
  6    select round(months_between(sysdate, a.dt_nascimento) / 12)
  7      into l_age
  8      from ator a
  9      where a.id = par_id;
 10
 11    return l_age;
 12  end;
 13  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_age(5) from dual;

  F_AGE(5)
----------
        54

SQL>
```